# How to change the column names when merging in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have three lists as follows.

```
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['no1', 'no2', 'no3', 'no4', 'no5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J']}

dummy_data2 = {
        'id': ['no5', 'no3', 'no1', 'no8', 'no12'],
        'Feature1': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
        'Feature2': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}

dummy_data3 = {
        'id': ['no1', 'no2', 'no3', 'no4', 'no5', 'no7', 'no8', 'no9', 'no10', 'no11'],
        'Feature1': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 15, 12, 13, 23],
        'Feature2': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 15, 12, 13, 23]}
```

I want to merge these three lists to one pandas dataframe while renaming the columns. So, my output should look like as follows (Note: when merging the columns that have values to all the rows are only merged).

```
id, df1_Feature1, df1_Feature2, df2_Feature1, df2_Feature2, df3_Feature1, df3_Feature2
no1, A, B, O, P, 12, 12
no3, E, F, M, N, 14, 14
no5, I, J, K, L, 16, 16
```

I tried to do it as follows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data3, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2)
merged = pd.merge(df3, merged)
```

However, I prefer to do the `merge` in one line. Moreover, I did not find a way to do the remaing of the columns yet. Is there a easy way of doing this in pandas?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `id` is unique in each dataframe, you may use `pd.concat` with listcomp and set_index `id` for each dataframe

```
names = ['df1_', 'df2_', 'df3_']
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df_final = pd.concat([df.set_index('id').add_prefix(name) for name, df in zip(names, dfs)], axis=1).dropna()

Out[558]:
    df1_Feature1 df1_Feature2 df2_Feature1 df2_Feature2  df3_Feature1  \
no1            A            B            O            P          12.0
no3            E            F            M            N          14.0
no5            I            J            K            L          16.0

     df3_Feature2
no1          12.0
no3          14.0
no5          16.0
```

---

Another method is using `join`:

`Join` is just a special version merge and it support merging on multiple dataframes natively

```
names = ['df2_', 'df3_']
dfs = [df2, df3]
df_final =  (df1.set_index('id').join([df.set_index('id').add_prefix(name) for name, df in zip(names, dfs)], how='inner')
                .rename({'Feature1': 'df1_Feature1', 'Feature2': 'df1_Feature2'}, axis=1).reset_index())

Out[595]:
    id df1_Feature1 df1_Feature2 df2_Feature1 df2_Feature2  df3_Feature1  \
0  no1            A            B            O            P            12
1  no3            E            F            M            N            14
2  no5            I            J            K            L            16

   df3_Feature2
0            12
1            14
2            16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can name the columns right in the first step

```py
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['no1', 'no2', 'no3', 'no4', 'no5'],
        'df1_Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'df1_Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J']}

dummy_data2 = {
        'id': ['no5', 'no3', 'no1', 'no8', 'no12'],
        'df2_Feature1': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
        'df2_Feature2': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}

dummy_data3 = {
        'id': ['no1', 'no2', 'no3', 'no4', 'no5', 'no7', 'no8', 'no9', 'no10', 'no11'],
        'df3_Feature1': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 15, 12, 13, 23],
        'df3_Feature2': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 15, 12, 13, 23]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data3)
```

Second, the merge function needs to know on what column your dataframes join.

```py
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='inner')
merged = pd.merge(df3, merged, on='id', how='inner')
```

And the results:

```py
    id  df3_Feature1  df3_Feature2 df1_Feature1 df1_Feature2 df2_Feature1  \
0  no1            12            12            A            B            O   
1  no3            14            14            E            F            M   
2  no5            16            16            I            J            K   

  df2_Feature2  
0            P  
1            N  
2            L
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I need to do the renaming of the columns in the dataframe while merging. Do you know how to do that? :)

Comment: The merge function has the `suffixes` parameter, but not prefixes, unfortunately. You can of course rename your columns after the merge using `rename` function or use the other answer's approach (I think it technically adds prefix to your dfs' columns before concatenating).